# I can neither register on lang-8 nor HiNative

Tags: registration

'I'm having issues with lang-8 and Hinative:
http://lang-8.com/
Says theyve stopped registration and forwards you to HiNative.
https://hinative.com/de
When I try to register there, I never get the confirmation mail :(
Is there any way to contact their support or something?
Or can you tell me how to work around this issue?